WebAssembly module not initializing with Emscripten-generated JavaScript
I'm new to WebAssembly. Can you please help for the below issue? I was trying to get solutions from GitHub copilot but no luck.
I'm trying to create a minimal example of using WebAssembly with Emscripten. I have a simple C function that returns a fixed value, and I'm trying to call this function from JavaScript in an HTML file. However, the onRuntimeInitialized callback is never called, and the WebAssembly module does not seem to be initializing properly.
C code (minimal.c):
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t get_fixed_value() {
    return 42;
}

I compiled the C code to WebAssembly using the following emcc command. I got minimal.js and minimal.wasm.
emcc minimal.c -o minimal.js -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_get_fixed_value"]' -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["cwrap"]' -s MODULARIZE

HTML file (minimal.html):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Minimal WebAssembly Example</title>
    <script>
        var Module = {
            onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
                console.log("WebAssembly module initialized.");
                // Define the getFixedValue function
                window.getFixedValue = function() {
                    let getFixedValue = Module.cwrap('get_fixed_value', 'number', []);
                    return getFixedValue();
                };
                // Enable the button once the module is ready
                document.getElementById('getValueButton').disabled = false;
            }
        };
        console.log("Module object created.");
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="minimal.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Minimal WebAssembly Example</h1>
    <button id="getValueButton" onclick="getValue()" disabled>Get Fixed Value</button>
    <pre id="result"></pre>

    <script>
        function getValue() {
            if (typeof getFixedValue !== 'undefined') {
                let result = getFixedValue();
                document.getElementById('result').textContent = "Fixed Value: " + result;
            } else {
                alert("WebAssembly module is still loading. Please try again in a moment.");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I am serving the files using a local web server (Python's http.server).
Questions
Why is the onRuntimeInitialized callback not being called? I never see "Module object created." on the browser console. The same issue is seen on Firefox and Chrome.
Thanks!
